# How to fix "WiFi is Disabled" on Elementary OS?

Tags: wifi

Hi there recently I switch from windows to Elementary OS Juno, my WiFi does not work, I tried many ways, nothing worked. So I bought 2 wifi routers, but both say "Wireless is Disabled". I would appreciate your help, I'm a noob. I want at least one of those work, I'm currently using USB tethering.[image]

details:
HP Elitebook 8440P
Core i5

Wifi card: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection.

1st Wifi router: TPLINK TL-WN422G.

2nd Wifi router: 802.11 n wlan.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the proper driver for your wifi adaptor? Maybe you can find some information in ubuntu forum like this,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Please use the comment section for this kind of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your laptop from the spec sheet I found on HP's site, it looks like you have an Intel powered wired internet connection card, but your WiFi card is made by Broadcom. It's pretty common for boards to have network adapters from different manufactures but since the WiFi one is what's acting up, you likely need a Broadcom specific driver.

I found a very extensive guide as the top answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) AskUbuntu question with step by step instructions on setting up Broadcom drivers within Ubuntu and this should work for Elementary. This does look to take a bit of reading and paying attention, but it looks like it should help out!

Comment: Please use the comment section for this kind of answers. The answer section is exclusively for solving the question with a step by step procedure. You can update your answer with the steps from the link or i'll convert the answer to a comment. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

On version 5.1.....
Open Terminal,
Paste " sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source " and press 'Entere'.

that's it!
and MY thank to whoever posted it originally.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the command `nmcli radio wifi on`

This helped me with this issue.